# Is it possible that one of the mysql queries would interrupt?

Tags: mysql

I really didn't know how to call the topic, but I will try to explain it here.
So, for example, I have 6 queries in one page. Is it possible, that first five of them would be completed and the last one wouldn't be? Is there any possibilities? If there is, what should I do?
Hope you understood smth. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a possibility, for various reasons. However this should be the exception and not the rule.

The side-effects of such a situation are often mitigated by using [atomic operations and transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/ansi-diff-transactions.html).

Comment: Thank you. And by the way, is there any other way?